# map with concat in reversed order in ansible

Tags: ansible

`{{ ["1", "2"] | map('append', 'x') }}` is evaluated to `["x1", "x2"]`.
Is it possible to do something like `append`?  I mean `["1x", "2x"]`.

Comment: Based on the duplicate question that @Konstantin noted, you can use the ```^``` to  match the beginning of the list element like this: ```"{{ [1,2] | map('regex_replace', '^', 'x') | list}}"``` which produces ```[ "x1","x2" ]```.  Changing to match the ```$``` will produce ```[ "1x","2x" ]```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a slightly ugly but functional solution that will give you ["1x", "2x"] :

```
- name: Concat 'x' to each list element
  debug:
    msg: "{{ [1,2] | map('regex_replace', '(.*)', '\\1x') | list}}"
```

Tested on ansible 2.4. Note, your initial example with `map('concat', 'x')` did not work for me with ansible 2.4, I got a complaint about "TemplateRuntimeError: no filter named 'concat'".

Answer (score 0):

you could try this: join the list variable to a string, manipulate it with regex and then re-split it back to a list variable.

playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    - list_var:
        - "1"
        - "2"
        - "3"
        - "4"

  tasks:
  - set_fact: 
      manipulated_var: "{{ ( list_var | join(' ') | regex_replace('([0-9]{1})', '\\1x')).split(' ') }}"

  - debug:
      var: manipulated_var
```

output:

```
[root@optima-ansible ILIAS]# ansible-playbook concat.yml

PLAY [localhost] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "manipulated_var": [
        "1x", 
        "2x", 
        "3x", 
        "4x"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   

[root@optima-ansible ILIAS]#
```

Note that this regex, will try to match single digit entries, as your example suggests ["1", "2", "3"] etc.